# User classification

Tags: user-behavior, user-research, users, categorization

Are there any "standard" frameworks for user classification/categorization in terms of behaviour, frequency of use, expertise, loyalty, attitude to product etc? Examples could be: early adopter, casual user, heavy user, expert and so on.

I'm not looking for one categorization, but maybe a few that could help me understand and analyze user behavoiur and engagement, and their trends. I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

It's more related to product development rather than strictly UX but I hope it's not too far.

Comment: This could also be useful for developing personas

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for here is an [ontology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_(information_science)). However, on searching, I had difficulty finding a standard ontology for the domain of "user classification/categorization in terms of behaviour, frequency of use, expertise, loyalty, attitude to product etc".

There's an interesting article about [organisational and role ontologies](http://www.epimorphics.com/web/wiki/organization-ontology-survey) and how no-one has created a standard one yet, but that's not quite what you were looking for.

The [Open Knowledge Foundation has a lot of ontologies](http://data.okfn.org/data), but not the one you're looking for.

The [W3C list of Good Ontologies](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Good_Ontologies) has FOAF and GoodRelations (a data structure for e-commerce). That ought to have terms for your domain, but doesn't seem to.